# Drush make project versions when there is only dev available?

Tags: drush

Using Drupal 7.x.  If I specify a drupal module project in my make file with no version, for example:

```
projects[] = geocoder
```

and the project currently only has a dev version available (e.g. [geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module as of November 29, 2011):

[image]

will make grab the dev version?  Or do I have to explicitly specify the dev version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably should have just tried this before asking, but I tried it now.  My make file has:

```
projects[] = geocoder
```

And running make gives me the following output.

```
Project information for drupal retrieved.                                 [ok]
Project information for geocoder retrieved.                               [ok]
drupal downloaded from                                                    [ok]
http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.9.tar.gz.
geocoder downloaded from                                                  [ok]
http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/geocoder-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz.
```

So seems like yes it will grab the dev version if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If the project has both a *stable* release and a *dev* version available, you can force usage of the *dev* version using something like

```
projects[geocoder][version] = 1.x-dev
```

You can also directly pull the project from its Git repository with

```
projects[geocoder][download][type] = git
projects[geocoder][download][url] = "http://git.drupal.org/project/geocoder.git"
projects[geocoder][download][branch] = 7.x-1.x
```